# Bouncy Castle J2ME load existing private key

Tags: java, java-me, rsa, bouncycastle, private-key

I have a PEM or DER private key, an existing key. How can I load this key with

`PrivateKeyFactory.createKey or into an AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` ?

I tried this:

```
InputStream inKey = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/samsjava/user_key_pk8.der");
                byte[] binKey = new byte[inKey.available()];
                inKey.read(binKey, 0, binKey.length);
                inKey.close();


                privKey = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(binKey);
                keyPair = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(new AsymmetricKeyParameter(false), privKey);

                rsaPriv = (RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.getPrivate();
                rsaPub = (RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.getPublic();
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the thing in Java, which should get me on the right track for J2ME. Here is the code:

```
public class EncrypDecrypt {
private RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaPriv;
private RSAPublicKey rsaPub;
private BASE64Decoder decoder;
private BASE64Encoder encoder;

public EncrypDecrypt(){
    decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    byte[] buffer;
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("pathtofile.pfx");
        KeyStore kStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        kStore.load(in, null);

        PrivateKey privKeyEntry = (PrivateKey)kStore.getKey("Key Alias", null); 
        rsaPriv = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) privKeyEntry;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EncrypDecrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}

public String encrypt(String data){
    try{
        AsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new RSAEngine();
        eng = new PKCS1Encoding(eng);
        RSAKeyParameters publicKey = new RSAKeyParameters(true, rsaPriv.getModulus(), rsaPriv.getPublicExponent());
        eng.init(true, publicKey);

        byte[] encrypted = eng.processBlock(data.getBytes(), 0, data.getBytes().length);
        return encoder.encode(encrypted);
    }
    catch(Exception err){
        return "";
    }
}

public String decrypt(String data){
    try
    {
        byte[] encrypted = decoder.decodeBuffer(data);
        AsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new RSAEngine();
        eng = new PKCS1Encoding(eng);
        RSAKeyParameters privateKey = new RSAKeyParameters(true, rsaPriv.getModulus(), rsaPriv.getPrivateExponent());
        eng.init(false, privateKey);

        byte[] decrypted = eng.processBlock(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length);
        return new String(decrypted);
    }
    catch(Exception err){
        return "";
    }
}
}
```